# how to make video stabilizer?

Tags: video, video-processing

I'm new at this topic. All i want is some information about video stabilization that how it works and how we can develop a software to stabilize a video, also is there any site which provides a detailed study about video stabilization ? Hoping for a helpful answer.

Comment: On what system/platform would you need to use it on?

Comment: @lofihelsinki this is what need to know that what is the best plat form I got to know that this can be done use matlab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In most cases you look frame by frame where each pixel went.

Then you adjust a rectangle (the smaller the better the stabilization but the worse the resolution) so that every pixel is always roughly the same spot.

(The rectangle can't move outside of its parent.)

The pixels inside the rectangle get cropped out and converted into a new video.

So if the user shakes the camera down, up, down, up the rectangle moves up, down, up, down to compensate the movement.

The challenge here is to find the new position of a pixel. This is where the complicated algorithms and AI come into play.